# PHP Get Address from longitude and latitude

Tags: php, google-maps

I create a code to get longitude and latitude of the user and this variables are stored in **mysql** database.

I'm using this code below to have the address from longitude and latitude.

After a search in **stackoverflow** i found this script but it didn't give me anything no error and no result.

I tried to print the variable **$geolocation** and i have a result printed like this **33.8943186,35.505271199999996** but i don't have the full address :(

Can any body please help me to solve my problem and get the exact address of user ??!!

```
 $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;
     $request ='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);
    $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);
    if(isset($json_decode->results[0])) {
        $response = array();
        foreach($json_decode->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponet) {
            if(in_array('political', $addressComponet->types)) {
                    $response[] = $addressComponet->long_name;
print_r($response); // no error
            }
        }

        if(isset($response[0])){ $first  =  $response[0];  } else { $first  = 'null'; }
        if(isset($response[1])){ $second =  $response[1];  } else { $second = 'null'; } 
        if(isset($response[2])){ $third  =  $response[2];  } else { $third  = 'null'; }
        if(isset($response[3])){ $fourth =  $response[3];  } else { $fourth = 'null'; }
        if(isset($response[4])){ $fifth  =  $response[4];  } else { $fifth  = 'null'; }

        if( $first != 'null' && $second != 'null' && $third != 'null' && $fourth != 'null' && $fifth != 'null' ) {
            echo "<br/>Address:: ".$first;
            echo "<br/>City:: ".$second;
            echo "<br/>State:: ".$fourth;
            echo "<br/>Country:: ".$fifth;
print_r($response);// No error
        }
        else if ( $first != 'null' && $second != 'null' && $third != 'null' && $fourth != 'null' && $fifth == 'null'  ) {
            echo "<br/>Address:: ".$first;
            echo "<br/>City:: ".$second;
            echo "<br/>State:: ".$third;
            echo "<br/>Country:: ".$fourth;
        }
        else if ( $first != 'null' && $second != 'null' && $third != 'null' && $fourth == 'null' && $fifth == 'null' ) {
            echo "<br/>City:: ".$first;
            echo "<br/>State:: ".$second;
            echo "<br/>Country:: ".$third;
        }
        else if ( $first != 'null' && $second != 'null' && $third == 'null' && $fourth == 'null' && $fifth == 'null'  ) {
            echo "<br/>State:: ".$first;
            echo "<br/>Country:: ".$second;
        }
        else if ( $first != 'null' && $second == 'null' && $third == 'null' && $fourth == 'null' && $fifth == 'null'  ) {
            echo "<br/>Country:: ".$first;
        }
      }
print_r($response);// error
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @Blueblazer172 I want to get the address from longitude and lattitude stored in my db

Comment: thats a statement :P

Comment: @Blueblazer172 what you mean ?!

Comment: your code works fine on my machine ...

Comment: @Blueblazer172 why not in mine?! i have a https domain on godaddy linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127866/discussion-between-m7md-and-blueblazer172).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get full address, try this.

```
$latitude = 38.872292;
$longitude = -76.9698557;
$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.872292,-76.9698557&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$formattedAddress = @$output->results[0]->formatted_address;
```

That URL will return a JSON response when executed. You need to convert it into an object/array. In my case it is an object. Just traverse through the array and get the required key, which is `formatted_address` in this case.

Comment: i tired like this but i didn't have any output $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$latitude.','.$longitude.'&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$formattedAddress = @$output->results[0]->formatted_address;
print_r($formattedAddress);

Comment: I tried on ogofiddle and it's work but i don't know why didn't work on my machine do you have any suggestion

Comment: i tired on localhost and it's work but the problem is online

Comment: stdClass Object ( [error_message] => You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.
We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: console.developers.google.com/… [results] => Array ( ) [status] => OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ) stdClass Object ( [error_message] => You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: console.developers.google.com/… [results] => Array ( ) [status] => OVER_QUERY_LIMIT )

Answer (score 2):

```
$lat=52.722452;
$lng=1.099504;

$geolocation = $lat.','.$lng;
$request ='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'';
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $request ) );

$results  = $json->results[0];
$addr = $results->formatted_address;
$comp = $results->address_components;

$response=array();

foreach( $comp as $i => $obj ){
    if( in_array( 'political', $obj->types ) ) $response[]=$obj->long_name;
}

echo $addr;
print_r( $response );
```

Comment: i have this errors Undefined offset: 0 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  Notice:Trying to get property of non-object Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

You have to print out  `$response[]`!
`$geolocation` is just long and lat as it is defined in the Code.
For more help have a look at the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=de)

Comment: i tired to print $response[] like this print_r($response[]); and like this print_r($response['0']); and like this print_r($response);  but i have this message Notice: Undefined variable: response

Comment: where do you print_r() ?

Comment: @Blueblazer172 check above the places where i tried to print_r